# How to compute RMSE with respect to a 1:1 line in R

Tags: r

Does someone know how to compute RMSE with respect to 1:1 line in R? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x=1:50 # it's identity line
y=seq(0.5,25,0.5) # it's y=0.5x
plot(x, type='l')
lines(y, col=3)
rmse=sqrt(mean((y-x)^2))
```